# Stream webcam using ffmpeg/avconv to RTMP libx264 doesn't work

Tags: rtmp, avconv

i have been trying to stream my webcam to Ustream using RTMP.

using the standard command works great:

> "avconv -f video4linux2 -r 25 -s 320x240 -i /dev/video0 -f flv rtmp://host/pass"

but i encoutner a **15** seconds latency!
therefore i decided to compress the video using libx264.
i downloaded it and confirmed it is installed properly.
but when running this command:

> "avconv -f video4linux2 -r 25 -s 320x240 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p-f flv rtmp://host/pass"

on ffmpeg i get "Illegal instruction"
and under avconv it starts to stream but nothing is shown in Ustream channel.

output from avconv command

```
avconv version 9.14-6:9.14-1rpi1rpi1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the
Libav developers
built on Jul 22 2014 15:08:12 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
[video4linux2 @ 0x709740] The driver changed the time per frame from 1/5 to 1/30
    [video4linux2 @ 0x709740] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may
    be inaccurate
    Input #0, video4linux2, from '/dev/video0':
      Duration: N/A, start: 5069.991764, bitrate: 36864 kb/s
        Stream #0.0: Video: rawvideo, yuyv422, 320x240, 36864 kb/s, 1000k    tbn, 30 tbc
    [libx264 @ 0x70a9e0] using cpu capabilities: none!
    [libx264 @ 0x70a9e0] profile High, level 1.2
    [libx264 @ 0x70a9e0] 264 - core 130 r2282 1db4621 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC
    codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html -
    options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7
    psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1
    8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2
    threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1
    interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2
    b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250
    keyint_min=5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf
    mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.25
    aq=1:1.00
    Output #0, flv, to
    'rtmp:host/pass:
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
        Stream #0.0: Video: libx264, yuv420p, 320x240, q=-1--1, 1k tbn, 5 tbc
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo -> libx264)
    Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
    frame=   44 fps=  3 q=23.0 size=      26kB time=0.20
    bitrate=1071.8kbits/s    bits/s
```

what could be the problem? 
thank you in advanced

Comment: I assume the "`ffmpeg`" you are referring to is the old, dead, buggy counterfeit from the Libav fork.

Comment: yes. i need my raspberry pi stream live video to Ustream cloud so i can view it on a browser.
any thoughts?